# The meaning of $\mathbb{I}_{ \{s-k = t-j\} }$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory

The autocovariance function for $MA(q)$ process can be defined as:

$$\gamma(s-t) = \sigma^2 \sum^q_{k=0} \sum^q_{j=0} \theta_k \theta_j \mathbb{I}_{ \{s-k = t-j \}}$$

What is the **meaning of the subscript** in the $\mathbb{I}_{ \{s-k  = t-j \} }$? Does it denote the dimensions of the identity matrix? But in that case $k$ does not have to be equal to $j$ dor some combinations in the dual sum... Or is this some kind of condition that has to hold?

Comment: No, it is called an "indicator function") : it is a means to indicate the selection (Explaining the logical value $\mathbf{1}$) in the summation of the ordered pairs of indices $(i,j)$ such that $s-k=t-j$ ; those which are not such are not selected (logical value $\mathbf{O}$

Comment: @JeanMarie Aaah! So this means that $\mathbb{I} = 0$ if $s-k \neq t-j$ and  $\mathbb{I} = 1$ if $s-k = t-j$?

Comment: That's it .....